# Cloud server vs VPS vs Dedicated for web App

Tags: virtualhost, cloud-computing, dedicated-server

So I am not very into servers and I have few questions of which I don't know where I can get answers from and I hope someone here could easly help me out.

So I have a web app currently hosted on Godaddy with shared host. All the files are hosted on Amazon CDN + Cloudflare for the cache so I have no issues in terms of speed but for few reasons I am moving far far away from Godaddy.

I went through many hosting providers websites, saw many plans and I'm searching for something new.

My web app is not using that much bandwidth. Somewhere between 350GB monthly. Users that access the webapp are from around the world. All I want is speed speed speed and uptime.

As for the files I will be moving them to Akamai CDN. But those are the css's and js's.

For the php/html/xml files etc I will be changing a hosting plan.

Now my questions are: (please do not post specific hosting providers)

I don't know whether I should choose Dedicated Server, VPS server or Cloud server.

1. - 1. I know that cloud servers are datacenters all around the world. Doesn't that make it faster than dedicated and VPS since usually there is a datacenter near my user instead of accessing from where the the dedicated server is hosted?
   - 2. As for Dedicated server, it will be great to have my own IP address which I haven't got now with the shared hosting but if my server will be in Texas, people from Greece will have higher latency that having cloud server?
2. Does VPS Hosting have dedicated IP address for each domain?
3. I have found a dedicated server of which offers 2GB Ram. Will that be faster than my shared hosting which I have now? Usually how much ram does a shared hosting have? I have no idea about servers but 2GB sounds incredibly low.
4. As I'm new to servers, if I buy a dedicated host, will I be able to set it up? Or do dedicated server is for more experienced people?

I'd love comments, thoughts, ideas and anyone's experience with web apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that cloud servers are datacenters all around the world. Doesn't that make it faster than dedicated and VPS since usually there is a datacenter near my user instead of accessing from where the the dedicated server is hosted?

Generally, no. Most cloud services are the same thing as VPSes - you have a virtual machine somewhere in their datacenters. With multi-datacenter clouds like Amazon's you can deliberately place servers in several regional datacenters, but you have to do it yourself, and many VPS providers have multiple datacenters as well.

> As for Dedicated server, it will be great to have my own IP address which I haven't got now with the shared hosting but if my server will be in Texas, people from Greece will have higher latency that having cloud server?

Cloud servers can have dedicated IPs - in Amazon they're called "Elastic IPs". As for latency, see the paragraph above.

> Does VPS Hosting have dedicated IP address for each domain?

Generally it's one IP per VPS. You can usually request additional.

> I have found a dedicated server of which offers 2GB Ram. Will that be faster than my shared hosting which I have now? Usually how much ram does a shared hosting have? I have no idea about servers but 2GB sounds incredibly low.

Depends on the shared host, but 2GB is not "incredibly low" for a dedicated machine as you're not sharing with other folks on that box. 2GB can server a pretty good amount of traffic - likely quite a bit more than your current shared host.

> As I'm new to servers, if I buy a dedicated host, will I be able to set it up? Or do dedicated server is for more experienced people?

You can buy a managed dedicated server, where the host will keep it setup and generally give you a control panel for adding domains etc., or you can get an unmanaged one that you have to set up and maintain yourself. Unmanaged is generally quite a bit cheaper.